# How to make non-"Required" properties of Entity Framework required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a previous project in which I'm not authorized to change my entity models (e.g. profile). There are some properties in this model that are not marked with `[Required]` data annotation but I need to make them required for the sub system I'm working on. I'm looking for a clean way to do this

Employee model:

```
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
 public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

public string FirstName { get; set; }

public string LastName { get; set; }
```

I want to make FirstName and LastName required in my form temporarily without touching the model code

Comment: Create a view model and add the attributes to the view model then map your model property values to the view model

Comment: But you accepted and answer where you need to create the html manually? (which incidentally does not work because it wont be validated on the server and is missing important attributes for client side validation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I think "data-val" is validated on the server side, that's why I accepted that answer, isn't this true?

Comment: No, those attributes are generated by html helper methods for use by jquery unobtrusive validation on the client. They are not posted back (only a controls name/value pair is posted back) so the server knows nothing about them when receiving data from the client. Server side validation is performed by the `DefaultModelBinder` based on the properties validation attributes.

Comment: Oops, then I guess I'll have to go with either a separate View-Model for each of these entities or build new tuples on the fly? :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some attribute to View.

If you have `<input>` tag in UI then put this two attribute.

```
data-val="true" data-val-required="Price field is required."
```

And If you have `TextBoxFor` then

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.price,new {data-val="true" data-val-required="Price field is required."})
```

Add this to your view.

Comment: Thanks dude, but these validations seem to be done on the client's side?

Comment: @SinaBizbone : Yes This code will run at client side. If You want on server side then use partial view concept. You can make same name class as partial and give FirstName and Last Name as Required Field.